# Awake or Awaken Which one is correct?

Tags: meaning

- Were you awaken at 1 am yesterday?

Is this grammatically correct? Can you tell me meaning of awake properly? How is it used as Adj., and as verb by giving some examples?

- I awoke at 11 am today.

Is this correct? Actually, What is the difference between wake and awake? I have searched a lot on Google but all in vain. I am not getting their difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Awake* has two meanings:

- As an adjective it describes a person or animal's state. It may only be used as a *predicate adjective*, in the predicate of a clause, not as an *attributive adjective* before a noun:

  > <sup>ok</sup> John is awake and at work.
  >   <sup>∗</sup>  Awake John is at work.
- As a verb it is intransitive—it takes no object—and means “to become awake *(adj)*”. It is an irregular verb, with the past form *awoke*; two different past/past participles are in use, *awoken* and *awaked*:

  > I **awake** at four o'clock most mornings.
  >   I **awoke** at six o’clock this morning.
  >   I **have awoken/awakened** early only twice this month.

*Awaken* is a transitive verb requiring a direct object. It means “cause [someone or something] to become awake”. It is a regular verb: both the past and past participle forms are *awakened*:

> My wife awakens me if I oversleep.
>   My wife awakened me at seven o’clock.
>   He was awakened by a loud crash.

The verb *wake, woke, woken/wakened* is also used in both transitive and intransitive senses.

> I woke at four o’clock.
>   My wife woke me at four o’clock.
>   I was wakened at four o’clock.

In pre-20th-century texts *wake* may also have another meaning: to “stay awake”.

These verb uses are fairly complicated; but it is simplified by the fact that none of them are used much in colloquial English today (which is one reason why the past and participle forms are so variable). Instead, the phrasal verb *wake up* (past *woke*, past participle *woken*) is used in both transitive and intransitive senses:

> I wake up at four most mornings.
>   My wife woke me up at seven o’clock.
>   He was woken up by a loud crash.

You will need to recognize the different forms and meanings in your reading; but for your own work you can use *wake up* in any context or register.

---

<sup>∗</sup>  marks an utterance as ungrammatical

Comment: Damn cool answer!! Take my bow!! Can I say this thing: Mom, Can you please wake me at 6:00 am tomorrow? Is it correct to say?

Comment: @hellodear2 It is correct; but as I said, it's uncommon in colloquial speech, where we'd be more likely to say *wake me **up** at 6 am*. Your Mom probably won't mind, though!

Comment: I would assume it means something like,"I am bowing to you in acknowledgement of your superior answer.  Please accept this gesture from me."

Comment: @Jim: Now I feel stupid - it's '!!', two screamers, not 'l!'. Thank you for rescuing me from looking like an idiot forever.

Comment: I’m confused by the examples in answer above: The “awake is intransitive (no object)” using “have awakened” as example. Then the statement “awaken is transitive (requires object)” but example uses “was awakened” with no object. I get that it can be transitive and intransitive, but the example doesn’t support the answer.

Comment: @Bob Errors in this: 1. Awake, awaken, and wake can be used transitively or intransitively. 2. They are synonyms. 3. _Awakened_ is never the past participle of _awake_.

Comment: @Bob *was awakened* is in the passive voice, which employs the 'object' (properly the 'Patient', the entity which suffers the action) as the syntactic 'subject'.

Comment: @joiedevivre 3. *awakened* is the pp of the verb "awake", (someone) [was awakened by the alarm clock ...Fortunately awaken (which was originally one of the past tense forms of awake) is simpler. It's a regular verb, which means it has the usual past tense forms....](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awaken) 1. The cat awakened at dawn 2. The cat was awakened at dawn by a mouse.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I was looking at that entry in Merriam-Webster when I wrote this comment. Note that it says _awakened_ is the pp of _awaken_, not _awake_. The two alternative PPs of _awake_ that it lists on that page are _awoken_ and _awaked_. Even if you interpret it as saying that _awaken_ is a possible PP of _awake_, that wouldn't extend to _awaken**ed**_.

Comment: @joiedevivre StoneyB explained *two different past participles are in use*  It's the PP of awaken, the sentences in his answer remain perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA His example sentences are grammatically correct, but he listed the two PPs of _awake_ as being _awoken_ and _awakened_. (It is an example listed under "Awake has two meanings" and can only be explicitly referring to two past participles of _awake_). But that is incorrect. The two different PPs of _awake_ are _awoken_ and _awaked_. We agree that _awakened_ is actually the PP of _awaken_.

Comment: @joiedevivre I shall leave StoneyB to defend his own answer. But I will say this, I think you're unnecessarily nitpicking.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The errors are minor, here, I agree. But considering that they spawned a new question that confused a learner, I thought they were worth pointing out, nitpicking or no.

Comment: @joiedevivre You are of course right; I confused myself. *Awaked* is the contemporary alternative weak past of *awake*; *awæcnede* has not been current since OE. On the other hand, transitive *awake* (strong or weak) seems to have been in steady decline since about 1900, though it's enjoying a resurgence in the last couple of decades (an artifact, I suspect, of the sudden expansion in print of colloquial forms).

Comment: @joiedevivre See this [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wakened+him%2Cwaked+him%2Bwoke+him%2Cawakened+him%2Cawaked+him%2Bawoke+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwakened%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28waked%20him%20%2B%20woke%20him%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cawakened%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28awaked%20him%20%2B%20awoke%20him%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you. I completely agree with you that using _awake_ transitively is very uncommon. I think in the _transitive_ vs. _intransitive_ debate, my quibble has more to do with saying that _awaken_ is transitive. I think it is, oddly, not used intransitively in the past tense as often as _awoke_, but in the present and perfect tenses, I think it is often used intransitively.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is incorrect because awaken should be in the past tense if you are speaking of the day before. So it should read:

> Were you awakened at 1am yesterday?

Idiomatically speaking I would say it is more common (at least in the US) to say

> Were you woken up at 1am yesterday?

This blog is actually a really great reference if you read through it all: 
http://whosyoureditor.blogspot.com/2011/01/awake-vs-awaken-vs-wake-vs-waken.html

Comment: Can I say this: Were you awake at 1am yesterday?

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. Awake is the state of not being asleep. Where as awaken is the act of rising from sleep. Does that help clarify the difference?

Comment: Can you tell me difference between wake, awake, awaken?

Comment: I think the blog actually does a better job than I will of explaining but here's my try: wake is a verb, it is to emerge or to cause to emerge from the state of sleep; awaken is also a verb and means to cause to stop sleeping; awake can be both a verb or an adjective, as a verb it means to stop sleeping as an adjective it means not asleep.

Comment: Looking at your other comments if you want to know if someone has not been asleep at all. I would say, 'Were you awake at 1am yesterday?' because that means that the person was not asleep. If you used awakened or woken up that implies the person was asleep and something caused them to stop sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

As rhealitycheck says, "awaken" in this case should be in the past tense, "awakened".

Or perhaps you intended to use an adjective. "Were you awake at 1 am yesterday?"

In any case, "awaken" is a somewhat archaic word. In modern English we generally say "wake up". For example, "Did you wake up at 1 am yesterday?" or "Did someone wake you up at 1 am yesterday?" or "Were you woken up at 1 am yesterday?"

Comment: Actually I want to ask someone if she hasn't slept at 1am yesterday. So, how should I ask her? - Were you awaken at 1 am yesterday? OR Were you awake at 1 am yesterday?

Comment: *Awaken* is a verb.  *Awake* can be a verb or an adjective.  If you are asking about someone's condition, you need to use the adjective, so *awake* is the correct word.  (You would say "were you awake at 1 am yesterday?")